# HttpWebRequest com SSL

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, http, ssl

Quando tenho que reproduzir alguns passos (`GETS` e `POSTS`) de um acesso todo https utilizando `.net` necessito da utilização do `ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback`. Então ai veio a minha dúvida, é necessário declarar antes de fazer cada requisição web, em cada **get** ou **post**, ou só basta declarar na minha primeira requisição?

Abaixo vai um exemplo de uma requisição que está sendo feita:

```
postData = postData & "-----------------------------296631985423887--"
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = New RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(AddressOf ValidateServerCertificate)

url = "https://www.google.com.br"
req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url)
req.Method = "POST"
req.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:39.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/39.0"
req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "pt-BR,pt;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3")
req.Accept = "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8"
req.KeepAlive = True
req.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, sessao)
req.Referer = "www.google.com.br"

req.ContentType = "multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------296631985423887"
req.ContentLength = postData.Length

Dim swRequestWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream())
swRequestWriter.Write(postData)
swRequestWriter.Close()
resp = req.GetResponse()
```

Salientando que as informações são todas fictícias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isto é uma configuração global, uma vez atribuída, só desliga se você o fizer manualmente ou terminar a aplicação. Inclusive é recomendado configurar isto no `global.asax` em vez do código.